# Understanding multi input XOR and XNOR

Tags: logic

[This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/286696) post says:

**Fact-1:** $ \text{XNOR-3} =
 \text{NOT} (\text{XOR-3}) = \overline{(x \oplus y \oplus z)} = 
(x \oplus y)\odot z \ne x \odot y \odot z$ and $\text{XNOR-3}$ is even parity checker.

On similar lines, I thought:

**Fact-2:** $ \text{XOR-3} =
 \text{NOT} (\text{XNOR-3}) = \overline{(x \odot y \odot z)} = 
(x \odot y)\oplus z \ne x \oplus y \oplus z$ and $\text{XOR-3}$ is odd parity checker.

I tried preparing truth table:

[image]

it looks like

**Fact-3:** From the truth table, $(x\oplus y)\odot z = (x\odot y)\oplus z = $ even parity checker,
but fact 2 says $(x\odot y)\oplus z$ is odd parity checker.

**Fact-4:** From the truth table, $x\oplus y\oplus z=x\odot y\odot z = $ odd parity checker,
but fact 2 says $x\odot y\odot z$ is even parity checker

**Q1.** Did I made mistake in preparing truth table or in deducing fact 2?
I prepared column of $x\odot y\odot z$ as $(x\odot y)\odot z$ and column of $x\oplus y \oplus z$ as $(x\oplus y) \oplus z$. (I guess I deduced fact 2 wrong as explain till 4th question, but need confirmation.)

I guess this is where I made mistake:

- While it is true (**by convention**) that $\text{XOR-3} = (x\oplus y) \oplus z$,
- it is wrong (**by convention**) to say $\text{XNOR-3} = (x\odot y)\odot z$ and
- strictly $x\odot y\odot z = (x\oplus y)\odot z$ (again **by convention**)

**Q2.** Are all conclusions in above bullet point correct?
**Q3.** Is also $\text{XNOR-3} = (x\odot y)\oplus z$? (Since they have same values in truth table above.)
**Q4.** If yes (to Q3), then fact 2 will be wrong. Is it so?

Now I dont get why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1. Did I made mistake in preparing truth table or in deducing fact 2? I prepared column of ⊙⊙ as (⊙)⊙ and column of ⊕⊕ as (⊕)⊕. (I guess I deduced fact 2 wrong as explain till 4th question, but need confirmation.)

The truth table is correct, but fact 2 is false, like you had noticed in bullet 2: "it is wrong (by convention) to say $\underline{\text{XNOR-$3$=(⊙)⊙}}$ ", since XNOR-$3\neq$(⊙)⊙, so we can't substitute XNOR-$3$ with ⊙⊙ in fact $2$.

> Q2. Are all conclusions in above bullet point correct?

All correct.

> Q3. Is also XNOR-3=(⊙)⊕? (Since they have same values in truth table above.)

Yes, they are equivalent, truth table is one method, another way to think about this is, since we know that $\oplus$ is Associative, also $\overline{p\oplus q}=p\odot q$ and $p\odot (q\oplus r)=(p\odot q)\oplus r$ we have:

\begin{align}
&\text{XNOR-}3\\
=&\overline{(x\oplus y)\oplus z}\tag*{Definition}\\
=&\overline{x\oplus (y\oplus z)}\tag*{Associativity}\\
=&x\odot (y\oplus z)\tag*{$\overline{p\oplus q}=p\odot q$}\\
=&(x\odot y)\oplus z\tag*{$p\odot (q\oplus r)=(p\odot q)\oplus r$}\\
\end{align}

> Q4. If yes (to Q3), then fact 2 will be wrong. Is it so?

Yes, fact 2 is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of that post you refer to is that $\text{XNOR-3}$ is *not* a 'multi-$\text{XNOR}$, i.e. that it is not $x \odot y \odot z$, but rather the negation of the 'multi-XOR', i.e. it is $\overline{x \oplus y \oplus z}$

As such, when you say:

> $\text{XOR-3}=\text{NOT}(\text{XNOR-3})=\overline{x \odot y \odot z}$

your mistake is that you assumed that $\text{XNOR-3}=x \odot y \odot z$ after all. No, it is not.

Comment: Thats precise mistake I did which followed in my further thoughts. Can you please confirm if these all (in) equivalences correct?: $\text{XNOR-3} (x\odot y \odot z)=\overline{x\oplus y\oplus z}=(x\oplus y)\odot z=(x\odot y)\oplus z\neq (x\odot y)\odot z$ and $\text{XOR-3} (x\oplus y \oplus z)=(x\oplus y)\oplus z$. (There was pointwise answer yesterday which had such equivalences. I didnt read it full. Unfortunately, it seems to have deleted now.) Also I didnt get answer for Q3. Its included in equivalences.

Comment: In above comment, with "$\text{XNOR-3} (x\odot y \odot z)$", I mean lets symbolically represent $\text{XNOR-3}$ as  $x\odot y \odot z$. Similarly $\text{XOR-3}(x\oplus y \oplus z)$ means lets symbolically represent $\text{XOR-3}$ as $x\oplus y \oplus z$.